# Как научить дотнетовский бандлер JS (System.Web.Optimization) понимать AMD модули?

Tags: javascript, .net, сборка, amd

**Дано:**
Проект в котором сборка js/css бандлов производится с помощью дотнетовского бандлера `System.Web.Optimization`.

**Вопрос:**
Как научить этот бандлер разворачивать джаваскриптовские [amd модули](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#amd)? То есть модули вида:

```
define(['myModule'], function(MyModule){})
```

То есть в результате я хочу получить один-несколько js-бандлов на основе указанных одной-нескольких точек входа и зависимостей, которые бандлер должен взять из описания модулей и возможно какого-нибудь конфига.

Сейчас при попытке обернуть свой класс в модуль я вполне предсказуемо получаю в консоли `define is not defined`.

То есть я хочу чтобы бандлы строились на основе дерева `amd` зависимостей и как это умеют `webpack` или `r.js`, мне нужна возможность писать нормальные модули, при этом желательно не меняя сборщик

Comment: а можно пример небольшой с несколькими модулями как они используются и пример _развернутого_ скрипта?

Comment: @Grundy, ок, добавлю минут через 20. Но не особо вижу чем может помочь "развернутый скрипт" если Вы имеете в виду js а не конфиг сборки

Comment: да, имел ввиду `js`, конфиг сборки, кстати, тоже можно добавить, чем больше информации тем лучше

Comment: @Grundy, так нет еще js модулей. Я хочу стандартный amd как в requirejs. http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#amd.
Распространенные бандлеры синтаксис такой понимюат.

Comment: Если можно научить понимать другой популярный формат модулей, тоже наверное ок. Но все таки хотелось бы амдшный и не париться

Comment: Не, после обработки бандлера, должен получиться какой-то код. Вот пример этого кода я и хочу увидеть. Если _Я хочу стандартный amd как в requirejs._ то можно тупо в бандл первой строкой этот requirejs и впихнуть

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43351/discussion-between-grundy-and-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Web.Optimization` - устаревший механизм, который больше не развивается. Динамическое построение списка файлов для бандла на основе содержимого файлов для него не делали и уже не сделают - так что без смены бандлера ваша задача не решаема.

Comment: Ага, спасибо, я его уже выпилил и впилил вебпак. Мне просто пока лень полно расписывать все что я делал

Comment: @Утка ну, в новой версии asp.net тоже так сделали :)

Comment: Ага, знаю. До этого я тоже докопался)

Comment: Там правда вроде галп с грантом?

Comment: ...которые же вызывают webpack, разве нет?..

Comment: Ну да, хоть черта лысого)